# Getting SVN running on Snow Leopard (not Server)

Tags: svn, mac-osx

I thought this would be easier than it is appearing to be.

I'm running Snow Leopard 10.6.4

I'd like to use this machine as an Subversion repository for other's on the LAN.

Getting Apache running is easy (actually so easy that it was deceiving...turns out it's just a checkbox in preferences).

But now I'm stuck on the best way to go about installing Subversion to run with Apache. There's plenty of tutorials but most that I've found are significantly out of date (and/or seem to rely on a mish-mash of 3rd party add-on software such as Fink or MacPorts).

Any tips on the most painless way to get SVN installed? I did grab the latest Subversion DMG from collab.net which will give me a PKG file. Not sure where to go from there, though.

EDIT:

*sigh*. I think I was duped by thinking it *should* be harder than it was. Like an idiot, it didn't occur to me to just run the pkg file. Turns out that's all it took. 'doh!

Answer (score 1):

You could run `svnserve`; then you wouldn't need Apache:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html

(I assume it works on OS X; it certainly works on Windows and Linux.)

Comment: Yea, that was my error too. Assuming it would 'just work' on OSX as easily as it does on Ubuntu. It seems that my confusion is that there are so many 3rd party packages/bundles/compiles for OSX that I'm not sure which to use where.